# Can I ask a question about a specific camera's wi-fi problem in photo SE?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Can I ask a question about its wi-fi without getting down-voted in Photography Stack Exchange?

Comment: Why the fear of downvotes? You know they are just fake internet points; right? :)

Answer (score 4):

> Can I ask a question about a specific camera's wi-fi problem in photo SE?

Sure, why not? Assuming the problem is actually with the camera, or about the camera's configuration, it seems on-topic to me.

Wi-fi issues that are clearly due to computer/router (mis)configuration, or otherwise related to computer equipment that isn't specifically photography-related are probably off-topic.

> Can I ask a question about its wi-fi **without getting down-voted** in Photography Stack Exchange?

That's a different question, and there's no guarantee you won't get downvoted. However, if the question is well-written (see the help center page [How do I ask a good question?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)), and shows clear effort to understand the problem and *communicate the problem clearly* to the Photo.SE readers, the chances of being downvoted are low.

Comment: I agree, downvotes are for poorly researched and poor quality questions. Close votes on the other hand will determine if it gets closed as off topic and aren't directly related to downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I generally agree with @scottbb. That said:

**The more this is about the context of a photographic workflow, the better**. If it's about transferring your photos in the field, that's on topic. If it's about some odd foible with particular hardware, same.

If it's about programming or reverse-engineering the protocol, it's probably still on topic but more of a gray area — and more to the point, I've not generally seen those kind of questions get good answers (and you're probably better off on a Stack Exchange site focused on that kind of thing).

On the other hand, if it's about hacking the wifi on your camera to be a hotspot detector or something like that, it's off-topic (even though a camera is involved).

I *like* these "how do I use high-tech interface of current photo gadget" questions less than questions about photography itself as an art. I wish we had a higher ratio of *those* questions. I also like them less than questions about the fundamentals of cameras regardless of special features of specific models. But in any case, we've certainly accepted them as on topic since the beginning, and hopefully those kind of questions will be interesting enough to help contribute to building the community of people asking and answering the *photography* questions.

Comment: Much better answer than mine. The *context* of the issue is more important than the device the problem resides in.